# submit form in javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have a select dropdown -

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post">                      
            <select name="assettypeid" id="assettypeid" onchange="typechanged();">
                <sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
                SELECT id, name FROM assettype order by name
                </sql:query>
                <option value="1">-- All Asset Types--</option>
                <c:forEach var="row" items="${queryresults.rows}">
                <option value="<c:out value="${row.id}"/>"
                <c:if test="${row.id == param.assettypeid}">
                <c:out value="selected"/>
                </c:if>
                ><c:out value="${row.name}" />
                </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            </form>
```

and then the function (I am attempting a form creation / submission in the function because typechanged together with post (in the main jsp) is unreliable and I don't want to have a submit button) -

```
function typechanged()
{
    typechosen = document.getElementById("assettypeid").value;
    alert(typechosen);

    var newform = document.createElement("form");
    newform.action = "";
    newform.method = "post";

    product = document.createElement("input");
    product.value = document.getElementById("assettypeid").value;
    product.name = "assettypeid";

    newform.appendChild(product);
    document.getElementById('newform').submit();
}
```

The alert part is working perfectly (so I know it is picking up the correct element and value), the form / post part (which should post back to the same jsp) does not post.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

newform it's a variable, it's not an element. You created the element with the name "form" and the variable that holds it with "newform" so you should change the submit to:

```
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use :

```
newform.submit();
```

Instead of :

```
document.getElementById('newform').submit();
```

You don't set the ID of the new form, so you can't use getElementById.

Comment: newform.submit() also does not work, nacho - I cant use myform because that is unreliable (when using typechanged), hence the attempt to pick up the assettypeid vale and post it in a new form.